# How to create a summary row in Pandas from audit fields

Tags: python, pandas

I am trying to derive a single row based on original input and then various changes to individual column values at different points in time.  I have simplified the list below.

```
I have read in some data into my dataframe as so:

    A    B    C  D   E

0   h    h    h  h   h 
1   x
2        y       1    
3             2  3


row 0 - "h" represents my original record.
rows 1 - 3 are changes over time to a specific column

I would like to create a single "result row" that would look something like:

'x', 'y, '2', '3' 'h'
```

Is there a simple way to do this with Pandas and Python with out excessive looping?

Comment: You mean get the last present value for each column? Also, please output `your_df.to_dict('index')`

Answer (score 1):

You can get it as a list like so:

```
>>> [df[s][df[s].last_valid_index()] for s in df]
['x', 'y', 2, 3, 'h']
```

If you need it as appended or something with a name, then you need to provide it with an index and then append it, like so:

```
df.append(pd.Series(temp, index=df.columns, name='total'))
# note, this returns a new object
# where 'temp' is the output of the code above
```

Comment: This did it - thanks.  I did have to replace empty '' lines with numpy.nan - and then this did the trick.

Answer (score 0):

You can just try

```
#df=df.replace({'':np.nan})
df.ffill().iloc[[-1],:]
```

Comment: I went with the last_valid_index approach - but your answer clued me in to the replacing '' with NaN.  Thanks for the help